# Pop-up saying element not interactable Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

There are two pop-ups: One that asks if you live in California and the second one looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

The second pop-up doesn't show up every time and when it doesn't the function works. When it does I get an `element not interactable` error and I don't know why. Here is the inspector for the second pop-up close-btn.

[image]

```
test_data = ['Los Angeles','San Ramon']
base_url = "https://www.hunterdouglas.com/locator"

def pop_up_one(base_url):
    driver.get(base_url)
    try:
        submit_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='No, I am not a California resident']")))
        submit_btn.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        url = driver.current_url
        submit_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'icon')]")))
        print(submit_btn.text)
        #submit_btn.click()
    except Exception as t:
        url = driver.current_url
        print(t)
        return url
    else:
        url = driver.current_url
        print("second pop_up clicked")
        return url
```

I have tried selecting by the aria-label, class_name, xpath, etc. the way I have it now shows that there is a selenium web element when I print just the element but it doesn't let me click it for some reason. Any direction appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 41 elements on that page matching the `//*[contains(@class,'icon')]` XPath locator. At least the first element is not visible and not clickable, so when you trying to click this `submit_btn` element this gives `element not interactable` error.
In case this element is not always appearing you should use logic clicking element only in case the element appeared.
With the correct, unique locator you code can be something like this:

```
submit_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='No, I am not a California resident']")))
submit_btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
url = driver.current_url
submit_btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('button[aria-label="Close"]')
if(submit_btn):
    submit_btn[0].click()
```

Here I'm using `find_elements_by_xpath`, this returns a list of web elements. In case element was not found it will be an empty list, it is interpreted as Boolean False in Python.
In case the element is found we will click on the first element in the returned list which will obviously the desired element.
**UPD**
See the correct locator used here.
It can also be in XPath syntax as `//button[@aria-label="Close"]`

Comment: Thank you! I will add the logic and keep looking for a unique identifier. I have posted a screenshot of the exact element I’m looking for with the developer inspector pulled up to show the button tag. I have tried as many different ways I can think of to extract it. Can you take a quick look at it to see if there’s an coats or css_selector that would work? It’s the button tag in the screenshot. Thank you again!

Comment: How can I make the second pop-up appear? I couldn't see it.

Comment: It seems to be random. Like every 4th time. Does the screenshot help? It is the second screenshot but it should show the html for the element.